# Lower Bound Recurrence $P(0) = 1, P(i) \ge 1-(1-\frac{P(i-1)}{a})^a$ by $\frac{1}{i+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I have a recurrence:

For any $a\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge2} $, let  $P(0) = 1$ and
$$P(i) \ge 1-\left(1-\frac{P(i-1)}{a}\right)^a.$$

I figured this should be lower bounded by $\frac{1}{i+1}$ (I looked at plot and tested millions of values).
[image]

However, I can't figure out how to bound it.
Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get things wrong, let me know, please.

By induction, it suffices to prove that
$$\left(1-\frac1{ai}\right)^a\leq 1-\frac1{i+1},\qquad i=1, 2, \cdots,$$
which is equivalent to
$$a\log\left(1-\frac1{ai}\right)\leq \log\left(1-\frac1{i+1}\right),\qquad i=1, 2, \cdots.$$
Let
$$f(x)=a\log\left(1-\frac1{ax}\right)-\log\left(1-\frac1{x+1}\right),\qquad x\geq 1,$$
then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=a\frac{\frac1{ax^2}}{1-\frac1{ax}}-\frac{\frac1{(x+1)^2}}{1-\frac1{x+1}}\\
&=\frac a{(ax-1)x}-\frac1{x(x+1)}\\
&=\frac{a+1}{x(ax-1)(x+1)}>0,\qquad x\ge 1.
\end{align*}
Hence $f$ increases to $0$ as $x$ increasing to $\infty$. Therefore, $f(x)<0$ for all $x\geq 1$, as desired.

Comment: Damn, you are good at this, thanks! As to my understanding, all steps should be correct.

Comment: @Krampfmeister You’re welcome. I’m glad to help.